# Is there a workaround to trigger an option.click event in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a dropdown to allow the user to sort search results. These results in a table but not all of the sortable criteria are represented by columns. The columns can be sorted by either clicking on the column header or using a 'Sort By' dropdown. The user can reverse the sort by clicking on the sorted columns header. I am trying to duplicate this functionality in the drop down but can't get it to work in IE7/IE8.

The following is the existing code that works in both IE and Firefox. It changes the sorted column but not the sort direction.

```
$("#sortSelect").change(function() {
    //change sort
});
```

This is what I am trying to change it to and it works in Firefox. It changes the sorted column and if the sorted columns is already selected it will change the sort direction.

```
$("#sortSelect option").click(function() {
    //change sort
});
```

I was hoping someone would know of a way to trigger the option.click event or know of a good workaround.

Comment: FWIW, as a user I think I'd find that a fairly strange user interface. If I'm looking at a drop-down list, I don't expect anything to change if I re-select the already-selected option.

Comment: is the #sortSelect element dropdown style or list style (ie does it have a size attribute) ?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - I am making the change based on user feedback. they want to be able to reverse the sort on columns not being displayed.

Comment: @SBUJOLD - It's a select element with no set sizes

Comment: @T.J. Agreed there.  Changing the sort order would normally be a separate box or button.

Comment: I agree it's not the most intuitive design, I'll look into alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate what T.J. Crowder said in the comments, this is an awkward change that you're making to a user interface.  That being said, it's possible to distinguish between clicking on the `select` element and clicking on an `option` element **if the select doesn't have the `multiple` attribute set**.  Try out the following code in Internet Explorer:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("#sortSelect").click(function (event) {
    if (event.offsetY > this.offsetHeight)
      $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).click();
  });
  $("#sortSelect option").click(function (event)
  {
    alert('clicked option '+this.parentNode.selectedIndex);
  });
});
```

It works because when you click on an option element, the click event fires on the select element.  By detecting that you've clicked outside the bounds of the select element checking `event.offsetY > this.offsetHeight`, you can use jQuery to trigger the click event of the currently selected option element.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I agree about the interface and will look into alternatives. Thanks!