# Jquery click event inside each loop not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click, each

I've inherited this bit of code and I'm trying to get it working. It's generating a select menu that's being used to filter a page of products. Originally, it was generating a UL (options were LIs), but it's now being converted to a select list. The options are appearing perfectly in all browsers, and the click works great in every browser except IE (all versions). In IE, I can use the drop down, but nothing happens when I click an option.

I've tried changing the event to change and select, but that only seems to break everything.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$.each(hazardClassification, function (i) {
                cleanMenuforClass = hazardClassification[i].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_').replace(/&./g, '_').replace(/\,/g, '').replace('/', '').replace('.', '');


                $("<option/>", {
                    "class": cleanMenuforClass,
                    click: function (event) {
                        $("#legend-inline-search").val("");
                            $("#pipemarker-type-selection div.product-container").css('display', '');
                        var clickedInput = $(this).attr("class");
                        var clickedCheckbox = $(this);
                        if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
                                filterItems(hazardClassification[i], clickedInput, countItems, selectedItemsContainer, clickedCheckbox);

                            } else {
                                removeFilter(hazardClassification[i], clickedInput, countItems, selectedItemsContainer);
                            }

                    }
                }).appendTo("#filter-by-classification select").append('<span>' + hazardClassification[i] + '"<span>');

        });
```

UPDATED: found a workaround that still uses jQuery and keeps things simple for the dummy designer (that's me). [Is there a workaround to trigger an option.click event in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561378/is-there-a-workaround-to-trigger-an-option-click-event-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with IE. IE selects (when option are involved) always have non strange behaviours.

i found this in a newsgroup.

> We can't use native events to click on  an  element in IE. IE
>   always reports height and width of 0 for  option elements, so there's
>   no way to calculate where the click point  should be.

and so i think you have to use a javascript workaround instead of using the jquery "click" event

Comment: Yeah, I hand kind of figured that part out, that IE just doesn't get this. I was hoping for a jQuery solution, at least some way to trigger a select event, but it seems I'll have to try another method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(hazardClassification, function (i) {
                cleanMenuforClass = hazardClassification[i].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_').replace(/&./g, '_').replace(/\,/g, '').replace('/', '').replace('.', '');


                $("option", {
                    "class": cleanMenuforClass,
                    click: function (event) {
                        $("#legend-inline-search").val("");
                            $("#pipemarker-type-selection div.product-container").css('display', '');
                        var clickedInput = $(this).attr("class");
                        var clickedCheckbox = $(this);
                        if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
                                filterItems(hazardClassification[i], clickedInput, countItems, selectedItemsContainer, clickedCheckbox);

                            } else {
                                removeFilter(hazardClassification[i], clickedInput, countItems, selectedItemsContainer);
                            }

                    }
                }).appendTo("#filter-by-classification select").append('<span>' + hazardClassification[i] + '"<span>');

        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just makes it so the options don't generate in IE. Thanks, though!